# My Histogram that I create in an array is not equal to 1

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

Here is my following code.

```
double calculateImageEntropy(Mat image, int sizeReduction)
{
    // Manually calculating the histogram.

    long double imageHistogram[256];
    fill_n(imageHistogram, 256, 0);

    int tempPixelValue = 0;
    long double grayTotal = ((image.cols - sizeReduction) * (image.rows - sizeReduction));
    for (int a = 0 + sizeReduction; a < image.cols - sizeReduction; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0 + sizeReduction; b < image.rows - sizeReduction; b++)
        {
            tempPixelValue = image.at<uchar>(b, a);
            imageHistogram[tempPixelValue] = (imageHistogram[tempPixelValue] + (1 / grayTotal));

        }
    }




    /*long double normHist[256];
    fill_n(normHist, 255, 0);

    normalize(imageHistogram, normHist, 0, image.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
    */
    long double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        total = total + imageHistogram[i];
    }
    cout << total << "\n\n";





    long double tempValue = 0;
    long double tempEntropy = 0;
    long double cumulativeEntropy = 0;
    long double finalEntropy = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < 255; y++)
    {
        tempValue = imageHistogram[y];
        if (tempValue != 0)
        {
            tempEntropy = tempValue * log2(tempValue);
            cumulativeEntropy = cumulativeEntropy + tempEntropy;
        }
        else;
    }


    finalEntropy = cumulativeEntropy * (-1);
    return finalEntropy;
}
```

I'm using OpenCV to load images and trying to calculate the entropy of an image. I want to normalize the images so that way bigger images won't have a bigger entropy because of size.

But I can't find why my normalised histogram doesn't equal to 1.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: floating point sums will almost never exactly equal an exact value.

Comment: You are using "i<255", but you probably meant "i<256".

Comment: Where 256 should be a constant (or a #define, but const is preferred in C++). The only "naked" integers permissible in code are 0 and 1, everything else should be constants.

Comment: If floating point sums will never equal to 1, surely there is no way that I can process different sized images effectively?